# Reorder and regroup multiple columns by date

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, vlookup, array-formulas

I'm a bit stumped on this one, would love some help on this :)

Here is my data :

```
+--- Col A --+- Col B --+-- Col C ---+--- Col D --+- Col E --+-- Col F ---+
|                FRANCE              |               ITALY                |
|     DATE   | Installs | Uninstalls |    DATE    | Installs | Uninstalls |
+---+----------------+----------------------------------------------------+
| 14/09/2020 |        1 |          2 | 14/09/2020 |        1 |          2 |
| 15/09/2020 |        3 |          1 | 17/09/2020 |        4 |          1 |
| 16/09/2020 |        1 |          2 | 22/09/2020 |        1 |          2 |
| 22/09/2020 |        3 |          1 | 26/09/2020 |        4 |          1 |
+------------+----------+------------+------------------------------------+
```

I am looking to group the results by date like this (one date = one line) :

```
+--- Col A --+- Col B --+-- Col C ---+--- Col D --+- Col E --+-- Col F ---+
|                FRANCE              |               ITALY                |
|     DATE   | Installs | Uninstalls |    DATE    | Installs | Uninstalls |
+---+----------------+----------------------------------------------------+
| 14/09/2020 |        1 |          2 | 14/09/2020 |        1 |          2 |
| 15/09/2020 |        3 |          1 |            |        0 |          0 |
| 16/09/2020 |        1 |          2 |            |        0 |          0 |
|            |        0 |          0 | 17/09/2020 |        0 |          0 |
| 22/09/2020 |        3 |          1 | 22/09/2020 |        1 |          2 |
|            |        0 |          0 | 26/09/2020 |        4 |          1 |
+------------+----------+------------+------------------------------------+
```

I am familiar with query, but having difficulties finding the right formula :(

Thank you in advance !!

Best

Comment: how many columns is your dataset wide?

Comment: On the example : 6
I have more countries in the real data set, all on the same format (DATE | INSTALLS | UNINSTALLS)

Comment: Do you have any formula you're working on? What did you try until now? Also, would you consider using an Apps Script [custom function](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions)?

Answer (score 1):

In [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64059360/reorder-and-regroup-multiple-columns-by-date#comment113278691_64059360) you mention

> I have more countries in the real data set, all on the same format (DATE | INSTALLS | UNINSTALLS)

#### **You can use a single formula**

```
={ArrayFormula(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(UNIQUE(SORT({A3:A;D3:D})),A3:C,{1,2,3},FALSE))), 
  ArrayFormula(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(UNIQUE(SORT({A3:A;D3:D})),D3:F,{1,2,3},FALSE)))}
```

You can add the next country by changing to the next set `G3:I` and adding the arrayformula part using the logic:

```
={ArrayFormula(...),
  ArrayFormula(...),
  ArrayFormula(...), 
  ArrayFormula(...),
  ArrayFormula(...)}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can recover all the dates by:

```
=UNIQUE(SORT({A1:A4;D1:D4}))
```

Then you can extract the corresponding installs for France by:

```
=ArrayFormula(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(UNIQUE(SORT({$A$1:$A$4;$D$1:$D$4}));$A$1:$C$4;2;FALSE)))
```

And by replacing `2` with `3` you can get the uninstalls. For Italy you replace `$A$1:$C$4` by `$D$1:$F4$`.

[image]