# Parse JSON into multiple sheets using Fetch() Google sheets

Tags: json, google-apps-script, google-sheets, fetch

I am trying to import a json file using Fetch() to populate multiple Google sheets
I have been trying for a few hours but I do not know enough to do this

The json is dynamic so its data is always changing but its structure remains the same
my json looks like

```
{
    "connections": [
    {
      "Id": 131527,
      "From": 49647,
      "To": 49644,
      "Name From": "Horus Max",
      "Name To": "Bob allison",
      "Initial Date": "9/21/2020 15:20",
      "Last Date": "9/21/2020 15:20",
      "Type": "",
      "Weight": 0,
      "Checkbox ZZZ": "",
      "Text Area": "",
      "Radio AAA": "value one AAA",
      "Select bbb": "value one sss"
    },
    { 

    },
    ],
   "elements": [
    {
      "Id": 49645,
      "Type": "Person",
      "Label": "Sally Yager",
      "First Name": "Sally",
      "Last Name": "Yager",
      "Description": "",
      "Segment": "555",
      "Image": null,
      "Project Name": "test222",
      "Initial Date": "09/29/2020 17:44",
      "Last Date": "09/29/2020 17:47",
      "Issues Checkbox": [
        "Option 1",
        "Option 6"
      ],
      "IssuesRadio": "Option 3",
      "Notes": "222"
    },
    {
    }
    ],
    "name": "My project name"
}
```

I need the elements data passed into a sheet called elements and the Connections data parsed into a sheet called Connections

Elements sheet
[image]

Connections sheet
[image]

What I get

[image]

I have

```
//=fetchdata("https://sum-app.net/projects/14312620200623668/download_data/kumu_json")
async function fetchdata(url) {
  var response = await UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
  var responseText = await response.getContentText();
  var responseJson = JSON.parse(responseText);
  
  // Return something to display in the Google Sheet.  
  var rows = [Object.keys(responseJson)]; // Retrieve headers.
  var temp = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < rows[0].length; i++) {
    temp.push(responseJson[rows[0][i]]); // Retrieve values.
  }
  rows.push(temp);
  return temp
}
```

Here is a Google sheet with what I get and the desired outcome
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/14vxiueXsUzFtkw22RHA7qVFE--PFVSwfj4zJIU7I3nk/edit?usp=sharing

Thanks

Comment: Questions should be self contained. While external links are welcome, consider adding a ascii table like ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63837444) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64059360)) or screenshots or csv text to show your data structure.

Comment: @TheMaster, I added images, I hope that works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Modification points:

- It is not required to use `await` to `UrlFetchApp` and the response.
- I think that in your script, each object and value from the top of response values are retrieved by `temp.push(responseJson[rows[0][i]]);`. `responseJson.connections`, `responseJson.elements` and `responseJson.name` are retrieved. By this, when `=fetchdata("https://sum-app.net/projects/14312620200623668/download_data/kumu_json")` is put to a cell, only `test222` is shown. I think that this is the reason of your issue. For example, when `temp.push(responseJson[rows[0][i]]);` is modified to `temp.push(JSON.stringify(responseJson[rows[0][i]]));`, all values can be seen. But I think that this it not the result you expect.
- In your goal, when you want to use the custom function, it is required to separate the script for "elements" sheet and "Connections" sheet.

When above points are reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Sample script:

Please copy and paste the folloiwng scripts. When you use this, please put `=GETCONNECTIONS("https://sum-app.net/projects/14312620200623668/download_data/kumu_json")` and `=GETELEMENTS("https://sum-app.net/projects/14312620200623668/download_data/kumu_json")` to the sheet of "connections" and "elements", respectively.

```
// =GETCONNECTIONS("https://sum-app.net/projects/14312620200623668/download_data/kumu_json")
function GETCONNECTIONS(url) {
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
  var responseText = response.getContentText();
  var responseJson = JSON.parse(responseText);
  var connectionKeys = Object.keys(responseJson.connections[0]);
  
  // At JSON object, the order of keys are not guaranteed. So the following array including the keys might be suitable.
//  var connectionKeys = ["Id","From","To","Name From","Name To","Initial Date","Last Date","Type","Weight","Checkbox ZZZ","Text Area","Radio AAA","Select bbb"];
  var data = responseJson.connections.map(e => connectionKeys.map(f => e[f]));
  data.unshift(connectionKeys);
  return data;
}

// =GETELEMENTS("https://sum-app.net/projects/14312620200623668/download_data/kumu_json")
function GETELEMENTS(url) {
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
  var responseText = response.getContentText();
  var responseJson = JSON.parse(responseText);
  var elementKeys = Object.keys(responseJson.elements[0]);

  // At JSON object, the order of keys are not guaranteed. So the following array including the keys might be suitable.
//  var elementKeys = ["Id","Type","Label","First Name","Last Name","Description","Segment","Image","Project Name","Initial Date","Last Date","Issues Checkbox","IssuesRadio","Notes"];
  var data = responseJson.elements.map(e => elementKeys.map(f => e[f]));
  data.unshift(elementKeys);
  return data;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This is great!.  All the data is present and correctly rendered. But the `Headers` are missing. Can these be put in?

Comment: @xyz333 Thank you for replying. About adding the header row, I updated my answer. Could you please confirm it?

Comment: Beautiful, Thank you Thank you Thank you

Comment: @xyz333 Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to refresh the data, you can add this to a menu or timmer

```
function refreshGETDATA() {
var queryString = Math.random();

/* Populate Chosen Elements Sheet */
var cellFunction = '=GETELEMENTS("https://sum-app.net/projects/14312620200623668/download_data/kumu_json",' + queryString + ')';
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Elements Sheet").getRange('A1').setValue(cellFunction);

/* Populate Chosen ConnectionsSheet */
var cellFunction = '=GETCONNECTIONS("https://sum-app.net/projects/14312620200623668/download_data/kumu_json",' + queryString + ')';
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Connections Sheet").getRange('A1').setValue(cellFunction);

SpreadsheetApp.flush();
}
```